# TypeError when awaiting dask futures

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, dask, dask-distributed

I get the following error:
`TypeError: object list can't be used in 'await' expression`

when I try to await futures as `dask_client.gather(futures)` or `await futures`.

I am using a Dask Client with `asynchronous=True`

Tried referring to the official docs https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/asynchronous.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `asynchronous=True` while initialising the dask client is not enough when you want to gather or wait for all futures to finish executing. `asynchronous=True` argument has to be passed to the gather method as well.

`await dask_client.gather(futures, asynchronous=True)`